# Binding datasource to an html <select> tag

Tags: asp.net

Is there any way to bind a datasource to an html select tag with `runat=server` attribute.

```
<select runat="server" onchange="showdistrict();" class="textbox" id="DpCity" name="DpCity">
    <option value="0">unknow</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Then why can't you use Dropdownlist?

Comment: because I'm binding my dropdown listboxes using Jquery Ajax and for preventing Enable validation error I use <select> tag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer myself so I'll share it.
by using runat="server"  attribute and assigning an id to control it will be accessible in code behind.
for example DpCity is my html select tag so I can use below code for binding datasource:

```
DpCity.DataTextField = "title";
        DpCity.DataValueField = "val";
        DpCity.DataSource = SrCity;
        DpCity.DataBind();
```

as like as an asp dropdown list box